# React native increases size of apk file by 6.5 MB

Tags: android, apk, proguard, react-native

I started testing size impact of using react-native in existing android project. When created a simple android project(template project with navigation drawer) and created .apk file, it's size was `1.1 MB` in release mode.

Then I tried to integrate react-native with it by following steps in doc, 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html

after completed this integration and updated my progaurd-rules.pro file with progaurd steps defined on here,
https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config/blob/master/Example/android/app/proguard-rules.pro

Proguard-rules.pro file contents are similar to,

```
# React Native

# Keep our interfaces so they can be used by other ProGuard rules.
# See http://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/466/
-keep,allowobfuscation @interface com.facebook.proguard.annotations.DoNotStrip
-keep,allowobfuscation @interface com.facebook.proguard.annotations.KeepGettersAndSetters
-keep,allowobfuscation @interface com.facebook.common.internal.DoNotStrip

# Do not strip any method/class that is annotated with @DoNotStrip
-keep @com.facebook.proguard.annotations.DoNotStrip class *
-keep @com.facebook.common.internal.DoNotStrip class *
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @com.facebook.proguard.annotations.DoNotStrip *;
    @com.facebook.common.internal.DoNotStrip *;
}

-keepclassmembers @com.facebook.proguard.annotations.KeepGettersAndSetters class * {
  void set*(***);
  *** get*();
}

-keep class * extends com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptModule { *; }
-keep class * extends com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule { *; }
-keepclassmembers,includedescriptorclasses class * { native <methods>; }
-keepclassmembers class *  { @com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIProp <fields>; }
-keepclassmembers class *  { @com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactProp <methods>; }
-keepclassmembers class *  { @com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactPropGroup <methods>; }

-dontwarn com.facebook.react.**

# okhttp

-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class okhttp3.** { *; }
-keep interface okhttp3.** { *; }
-dontwarn okhttp3.**

# okio

-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-dontwarn java.nio.file.*
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
-dontwarn okio.**
```

Now, size of my release .apk file has jumped to `7.9 MB`. This is too much. I can see various e-commerce  apps on play store with total size of `9-12 MB`. 
My Hybrid react-native app is the most basic app, Which has just two activities which are doing almost nothing.

To verify my findings, I created a new react-native app by following this doc,
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

When I generated release .apk file for this pure react-native project, again the basic `Awesome App` .apk size was `6.8 MB`.

This is unacceptable. React native is adding too much size to apk. 
Is there any further improvement possible in my `progaurd file`? Anything else can be done to improve this?

It will be really helpful, If anyone can share size impact on his/her app due to React native.

Comment: Related: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#enabling-proguard-to-reduce-the-size-of-the-apk-optional

Comment: I have already gone through this doc. I am using minify: true in my release build

Comment: Be aware that if you are comparing a Java Android app with any app build with a third party framework, you should expect the third party framework based app to add additional libraries which generally makes the project bigger.

Comment: Try `-repackageclasses com.yourpackage` and `-allowaccessmodification`.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I agree. But, 6.5 MB is too much. I was expecting progaurd to do a better job and keep the only relevant code. I hope that others would have faced/solved this problem as react-native is quite famous and widely used.

Comment: @user1643723 Could you please elaborate? Proguard document says that -allowaccessmodification is not good option for library code.

Comment: Proguard is only for Java classes not Javascript or any C/C++ binaries. And based on this YouTube video: https://youtu.be/8N4f4h6SThc?t=8m52s it appears that React Native bundles its own JavaScript VM for Android in addition to other Java class files.

Comment: @ggsrivas "Proguard document says that -allowaccessmodification is not good option for library code" - erm, what? You are not writing a *library*, that depends on React, do you?

Comment: @MorrisonChang I agree with you. But I still hope that there might be a way to optimize this. If not drastic improvement then at least a bit.

Comment: @user1643723 actually yest, I am writing an SDK which use react to render  UI. Anyways, I will try -allowaccessmodification and see if it helps. Thanks

Comment: As pointed out by @MorrisonChang React Native is bundling it's own Javascript VM in android apk and seems like that is architecture dependent.
If I split my apk to arm and X86, apk size is reduced by 50%. This explains why proguard was not very helpful.
Thanks for help guys!

Comment: @ggsrivas Interesting... I don't know what kind of SDK that is (something like Adobe Air, I guess?) but if you need to reduce total size, I recommend you to look into things like UPX-compression of native libraries (upx recently [has gotten support](https://github.com/upx/upx/issues/100) for Android shared libraries).

Comment: Add `splits enable true` and get it down to 4-2MB https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10350

Answer (score 0):

The size of apk when created using react-native will always be more than the native-app apk. But you can reduce your apk size when using react-native.

You can see [here](https://medium.com/@aswinmohanme/how-i-reduced-the-size-of-my-react-native-app-by-86-27be72bba640) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38184734/react-native-for-small-size-apk-with-low-internet-bandwidth/39433863) for how to do it.

It is preferred in the documentation itself that

> React Native is great when you are starting a new mobile app from
>   scratch. However, it also works well for adding a single view or user
>   flow to existing native applications.

So, I would prefer to create new react-native app instead of integrating with your existing one since you want to achieve the least apk size possible for react-native android app.